# parser dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have à dict like:

```
test =  {0: {'nom': 'toto', 'id':1}, 2: {'nom': 'tutu', 'id': 2}}
```

I would like print a result like

```
toto

tutu
```

I try

```
for nom in test :
   print test['nom']
```

But not working

Thanks

Comment: who are the people voting down this question? Can't you see he is new here. smh

Comment: @YankiTwizzy Even though people were able to figure out what "But not working" meant, it's still considered bad form to just say "it's not working" without an explanation of what that means (compile error? output not what you expect? computer exploded?) and the output of what is currently happening. I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing that is why people did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your first dict's key is number. Not 'nom'.

```
for k in test:
    print test[k]['nom']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 test = {0: {'nom': 'toto', 'id':1}, 2: {'nom': 'tutu', 'id': 2}}

 print ' '.join([test[ele]['nom'] for ele in test])
```

Comment: did you mean `values()` ?

Comment: No, @karthikr, its `.keys()`, where `test.keys()` will give you all the first level keys as a list

Comment: If you really mean `keys`, then it's better to omit it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
for nom in test:
       print (test[nom]['nom'])
```

This should work on Python 3 and 2. Using what is below would only work on 2

```
for nom in test:
           print test[nom]['nom']
```